# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model, mongoose.model called before schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I get error like this, these are stacktrace lines, from start:

this is my main node server file, where I load routes

```
require('./config/routes')(app);
```

this is routes file, will require

```
var todos = require('../app/controllers/todos'); controller
```

**This is controller, which gives the error, on line 2:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Todo = mongoose.model('Todo'),
_ = require('underscore');
```

Here is my model file, which does not seem to be called:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TodoSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});

TodoSchema.path("content").validate(function(content) {
    return content.length;
}, 'Content cannot be blank');

mongoose.model("Todo", TodoSchema);
```

So if I understand correctly, my problem is that this line(inside controller) is called:

```
Todo = mongoose.model('Todo')
```

Before this line, which is in my model:

```
mongoose.model("Todo", TodoSchema);
```

Right? However I took the stack from mean.io and few other , and put it together.

Lets look into mean.io code, they are doing the same thing:

server.js

```
require('./config/routes')(app, passport, auth);
```

then goes into routes.js, and code:

```
var articles = require('../app/controllers/articles');
```

then goes into articles controller:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Article = mongoose.model('Article'),
_ = require('underscore');
```

And this works correctly, but it is exactly the same order mine.

Comment: You need to require the Todo model file at some point before you try to assign mongoose.model('Todo')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `server.js` (https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/server.js), there's a function that is called to automatically load the models:

```
//Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models';

var walk = function(path) {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file) {
        var newPath = path + '/' + file;
        var stat = fs.statSync(newPath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            if (/(.*)\.(js$|coffee$)/.test(file)) {
                require(newPath);
            }
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walk(newPath);
        }
    });
};
walk(models_path);
```

This loads all the models defined in the `/app/models` directory. This would need to occur **before** your controllers which have references to the model types.

Comment: Gahh, I was skimming through the server.js file, saw this method, but seemed too complex to just create schemas, so skipped it. Is this a standard way to do it or more like "hacky"?

Comment: I've coded the exact same thing -- and I wouldn't consider it hacky. It's a pretty typical way of bootstrapping a folder full of files in NodeJS. You could do it manually by individually loading via a `require` for each file, ... but this is far more resilient to change.

Comment: @WiredPrairie This is what mean.io bootstrap uses.  It is so ugly though.